# finding previous rows that match current row in table

Tags: mysql, r, matlab

I have a basketball dataset with column A representing different teams. Is there a good way to extract the last few rows in that dataset where column A matched "The Warriors" for instance?

What I mean here is I want to find the last 3 rows before the current one where column A said "The Warriors" for example. How would I do this in R (or SQL or Matlab)?

Comment: Note that rows in an RDBMS table have no order other than that declared within the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a solution in Matlab.

Let me create at first a random table with a single column `A` just for the sake of demo:

```
T = 

          A       
    ______________

    'The Warriors'
    '43'          
    '38'          
    '40'          
    '49'          
    '71'          
    '69'          
    '64'          
    '67'          
    'The Warriors'
    'The Warriors'
    'The Warriors'
    '131'         
    'The Warriors'
    '119'         
    '124'         
    '93'          
    '109'         
    '77'          
    'The Warriors'
    '83'          
    '117'         
    '75'          
    '122'         
    '80'          
    'Smith'       
    'Johnson'     
    'Williams'    
    'Jones'       
    'Brown'
```

Now it's possible to create a boolean vector which contains `true` (1) in position `i` if the i-th row contains the string `'The Warriors'`:

```
matchresult=cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'The Warriors'),T.A);
```

Indeed now `matchresult` has the form:

```
matchresult =

     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

And now we can scan this vector instead of the whole table to find the last 3 rows:

```
for i=4:length(matchresult)                 % since we want 3 rows we can start scanning from the 4th
    if(sum(matchresult(1:i-1))>=3)          % if there are at least 3 ones in previous rows
        fprintf('Scanning row #%d:\n',i);   % see the row index we're scanning
        find(matchresult((1:i-1)),3,'last') % find 1s in previous rows and display last 3 indices
    end
end
```